# DOJO:FilteringSelect combo box is not appearing

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am very new to DOJO, I copied the code from internet but still its not getting the values from json file. Please advice if I need to use any server to run this code. 
the code is:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../_static/js/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css"
    />
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body class=" soria ">
    <label for="city">
        City:
    </label>
    <input id="city">
    <label for="state">
        State:
    </label>
    <input id="state">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        var cityJson = {
            label: 'name',
            items: [{
                name: 'Albany',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Albuquerque',
                state: 'NM'
            },
            {
                name: 'Alexandria',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Amarillo',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Amherst',
                state: 'MA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Anaheim',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Anchorage',
                state: 'AK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ann Arbor',
                state: 'MI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Annapolis',
                state: 'MD'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ashland',
                state: 'OR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Aspen',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Athens',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Atlanta',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Auburn',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Augusta',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Austin',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Baltimore',
                state: 'MD'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bangor',
                state: 'ME'
            },
            {
                name: 'Baton Rouge',
                state: 'LA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bethlehem',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Beverly Hills',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Billings',
                state: 'MT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Biloxi',
                state: 'MS'
            },
            {
                name: 'Birmingham',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bloomington',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Boca Raton',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Boise',
                state: 'ID'
            },
            {
                name: 'Boston',
                state: 'MA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Boulder',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Branson',
                state: 'MO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Buffalo',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Burbank',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Burlington',
                state: 'VT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Butte',
                state: 'MT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cambridge',
                state: 'MA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Carmel',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cedar Rapids',
                state: 'IA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Champaign-Urbana',
                state: 'IL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Chapel Hill',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Charleston',
                state: 'SC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Charleston',
                state: 'WV'
            },
            {
                name: 'Charlotte',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Chattanooga',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Chicago',
                state: 'IL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cincinnati',
                state: 'OH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Clearwater Beach',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cleveland',
                state: 'OH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cody',
                state: 'WY'
            },
            {
                name: 'College Station',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Colorado Springs',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Columbia',
                state: 'SC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Columbus',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Columbus',
                state: 'OH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Concord',
                state: 'NH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Corpus Christi',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dallas',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dayton',
                state: 'OH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Daytona Beach',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Denver',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Des Moines',
                state: 'IA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Destin',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Detroit',
                state: 'MI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dover',
                state: 'DE'
            },
            {
                name: 'Duluth',
                state: 'MN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Durham',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'El Paso',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Erie',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Eugene',
                state: 'OR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Evansville',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fairbanks',
                state: 'AK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fargo',
                state: 'ND'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fayetteville',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Flagstaff',
                state: 'AZ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fort Lauderdale',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fort Wayne',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fresno',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ft. Worth',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Galveston',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Gatlinburg',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Grand Forks',
                state: 'ND'
            },
            {
                name: 'Greensboro',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Greenville',
                state: 'SC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Gulf Shores',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hanover',
                state: 'NH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Harrisburg',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hartford',
                state: 'CT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hershey',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hollywood',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hot Springs',
                state: 'AR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Houston',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'Huntsville',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Indianapolis',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Iowa City',
                state: 'IA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ithaca',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Jackson',
                state: 'MS'
            },
            {
                name: 'Jacksonville',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Juneau',
                state: 'AK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kalamazoo',
                state: 'MI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kansas City',
                state: 'KS'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kansas City',
                state: 'MO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kennebunkport',
                state: 'ME'
            },
            {
                name: 'Key West',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Knoxville',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kodiak',
                state: 'AK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Laguna Beach',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lansing',
                state: 'MI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Las Cruces',
                state: 'NM'
            },
            {
                name: 'Las Vegas',
                state: 'NV'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lexington',
                state: 'KY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lincoln',
                state: 'NE'
            },
            {
                name: 'Little Rock',
                state: 'AR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Los Alamos',
                state: 'NM'
            },
            {
                name: 'Los Angeles',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Louisville',
                state: 'KY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lynchburg',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Macon',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Madison',
                state: 'WI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Manchester',
                state: 'NH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Mankato',
                state: 'MN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Memphis',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Miami',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Milwaukee',
                state: 'WI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Minneapolis',
                state: 'MN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Mobile',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Moline',
                state: 'IL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Monterey',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Montgomery',
                state: 'AL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Montpelier',
                state: 'VT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Morgantown',
                state: 'WV'
            },
            {
                name: 'Myrtle Beach',
                state: 'SC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Naples',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Nashville',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'New Haven',
                state: 'CT'
            },
            {
                name: 'New Orleans',
                state: 'LA'
            },
            {
                name: 'New York City',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Newark',
                state: 'NJ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Newport Beach',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Niagara Falls',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Norfolk',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Oakland',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ogden',
                state: 'UT'
            },
            {
                name: 'Oklahoma City',
                state: 'OK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Olympia',
                state: 'WA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Omaha',
                state: 'NE'
            },
            {
                name: 'Orlando',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Palm Beach',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Palm Springs',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Palo Alto',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Panama City Beach',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pasadena',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pensacola',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Peoria',
                state: 'IL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Philadelphia',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Phoenix',
                state: 'AZ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pierre',
                state: 'SD'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pigeon Forge',
                state: 'TN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pittsburgh',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pocatello',
                state: 'ID'
            },
            {
                name: 'Portland',
                state: 'ME'
            },
            {
                name: 'Portland',
                state: 'OR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Portsouth',
                state: 'NH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Princeton',
                state: 'NJ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Providence',
                state: 'RI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Raleigh',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Redondo Beach',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Reno',
                state: 'NV'
            },
            {
                name: 'Richmond',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rochester',
                state: 'MN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rochester',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rockford',
                state: 'IL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Sacramento',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Salem',
                state: 'OR'
            },
            {
                name: 'Salt Lake City',
                state: 'UT'
            },
            {
                name: 'San Antonio',
                state: 'TX'
            },
            {
                name: 'San Diego',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'San Francisco',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'San Jose',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Santa Barbara',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Santa Cruz',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Santa Fe',
                state: 'NM'
            },
            {
                name: 'Santa Monica',
                state: 'CA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Sarasota',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Savannah',
                state: 'GA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Scottsdale',
                state: 'AZ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Scranton',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Seattle',
                state: 'WA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Shreveport',
                state: 'LA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Sioux Falls',
                state: 'SD'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Bend',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Spokane',
                state: 'WA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Springfield',
                state: 'MA'
            },
            {
                name: 'St. Louis',
                state: 'MO'
            },
            {
                name: 'St. Paul',
                state: 'MN'
            },
            {
                name: 'St. Petersburg',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'State College',
                state: 'PA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Sun Valley',
                state: 'ID'
            },
            {
                name: 'Syracuse',
                state: 'NY'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tacoma',
                state: 'WA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tallahassee',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tampa',
                state: 'FL'
            },
            {
                name: 'Telluride',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tempe',
                state: 'AZ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Terre Haute',
                state: 'IN'
            },
            {
                name: 'Toledo',
                state: 'OH'
            },
            {
                name: 'Topeka',
                state: 'KS'
            },
            {
                name: 'Traverse City',
                state: 'MI'
            },
            {
                name: 'Trenton',
                state: 'NJ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tucson',
                state: 'AZ'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tulsa',
                state: 'OK'
            },
            {
                name: 'Vail',
                state: 'CO'
            },
            {
                name: 'Virginia Beach',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Washington',
                state: 'DC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Wheeling',
                state: 'WV'
            },
            {
                name: 'Wichita',
                state: 'KS'
            },
            {
                name: 'Williamsburg',
                state: 'VA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Wilmington',
                state: 'DE'
            },
            {
                name: 'Winston-Salem',
                state: 'NC'
            },
            {
                name: 'Worcester',
                state: 'MA'
            },
            {
                name: 'Yellowstone',
                state: 'WY'
            },
            {
                name: 'York',
                state: 'PA'
            }]
        };

        new dijit.form.ComboBox({
            store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                data: cityJson
            }),
            autoComplete: true,
            query: {
                state: "*"
            },
            style: "width: 150px;",
            required: true,
            id: "city",
            onChange: function(city) {
                dijit.byId('state').attr('value', (dijit.byId('city').item || {
                    state: ''
                }).state);
            }
        },
        "city");

        new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
            store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                url: '../../_static/js/dijit/tests/_data/states.json'
            }),
            autoComplete: true,
            style: "width: 150px;",
            id: "state",
            onChange: function(state) {
                dijit.byId('city').query.state = state || "*";
            }
        },
        "state");
    });
</script>
<!-- NOTE: the following script tag is not intended for usage in real
world!! it is part of the CodeGlass and you should just remove it when
you use the code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        if (document.pub) {
            document.pub();
        }
    });
</script>
```

any help is appriciated.

Thaks
PK

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this file "../../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js" on your site? If not, that could be your problem.